# Heroku PointDNS issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, dns

Can't seem to find a solution to this issue. I recently switched hosting over to Heroku and have needed to set up some custom DNS to change email MX records to my webmail host.

I configured them, however, it has been 48 hours and the emails are still not working.

It also says "Domain not resolving" in PointDNS, however, I can't seem to understand why and Google isn't helping out.

Here's a img of my setup: ! https://i.stack.imgur.com/oh9j9.png

Comment: Hey @Callum. Have you figured it out?

Comment: I have used pointDNS for years and had a similar problem, unfortunately they were not able to find the root cause so later on switch to another DNS service. so  i would recommend not to use poitnDNS.